# django.db.utils.OperationalError: near N: syntax error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, virtualenv

So I have a centos 6.6 on ec2.
Installed python 2.7, virtualenv for 2.7, pip-2.7 and created a virtualenv
install with my pip inside by virtualenv (2.7 all, promise) django 1.7.1

`startproject` works. I have my project. but:
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080` / `python manage.py migrate` and everything that use manage.py gets this error:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x1c43848>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/webapps/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 222, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
....
  File "/opt/webapps/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/opt/webapps/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 483, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "N": syntax error
```

I have no idea why this keeps happening. uninstalled & re-installed all but this error would stay anyway.
Google keeps suggesting south install / vagrant but I don't use them now.

Someone know what this thing is about?

BTW:
`which python`: /opt/webapps/env/bin/python

`which pip`: /opt/webapps/env/bin/pip

all in virtualenv in the right place and --version should 2.7

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this issue? Did you file a bug? I just installed Django 1.7.5 on a virtualenv and found this same exact issue.

Comment: Sorry. Never found a solution. I do believe it's something about changing from the default python 2.6 to 2.7, that somehow wasn't performed good enough. Or some language change that made this error pop up. Try using centos 6.4 and see if that works better. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`django.db.utils.OperationalError` occures when validation of one of migrations failed. So, you should check all migrations of your project for incorrect SQL-syntax ("N").